# Problem with NET TCP releasing connections

Tags: .net, wcf

I have an application that uses WCF and a net tcp based web service this runs on Windows 2008 R2 and .Net 4. Under heavy load we see the number of tcp connections rise up to 500, but never anymore than this, to suggest that there is some configured limit somewhere which we are yet to track down. After subjecting our application to this stress test, the number of TCP connections gradually drops, we are in the process of investigating this with wire shark. However, I was wondering if anyone else out there has experienced and, specifcally, if anyone can offer any trouble shooting advice / suggestions as to:-

1. Why we are hitting this 500 connection limit.
2. Why the connections seem to be queueing up and are not getting released earlier.

Note that we leave all the connection pooling to wcf, i.e. we do not explicitly programmaticaly handle this.

Answer (score 2):

The connection limit is set [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970231/objectcontext-executestorecommand-how-to-clear-parameters-between-calls), in the old days the problem with this was that the default was 2 or 10 depending on situation, but maybe that has changed to 500.

For the connections staying open, they will stay open until the client closes them or they timeout. Also check if you are using per session http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx