# ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand, how to clear parameters between calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am making multiple calls to ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand with different commands and different parameters, although I use the same parameter list (object) for a several of the commands.  I am getting the following exception:

`System.ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.`

Is there a way to clear parameters between calls as I would do with straight up ADO.NET?

**Updated with a code sample:**

```
    string sqlDeleteWebUserGreen = "delete WebUserGreen where WebUserId = @WebUserId";
    string sqlDeleteWebUserBlue = "delete WebUserBlue where WebUserId = @WebUserId";

    var argsDeleteWebUserXref = new DbParameter[] {
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "WebUserId", Value = user.WebUserId }

    rowsAffectedDeleteWebUserXref += base.context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlDeleteWebUserGreen, argsDeleteWebUserXref);
    rowsAffectedDeleteWebUserXref += base.context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlDeleteWebUserBlue, argsDeleteWebUserXref);
```

**UPDATE**

Basically I am unable to find any better way of doing this, so I ended up accepting the answer below.  The only difference is that I simply put the creation of the parameter into a separate method, so my calls look like `base.context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlDeleteWebUserBlue, MethodThatWillGiveMeTheParameterArray());`

Comment: Can you post your code? Sounds like you are reusing an object that should be disposed off after each use.

Comment: @Shiraz Bhaiji, I updated with the area that causes the exception.  In fact I don't want to dispose of anything, all of this is part of a transaction that has say 10 calls to .ExecuteStoreCommand()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same parameter twice.

try this

```
var argsDeleteWebUserXref1 = new DbParameter[] {         new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "WebUserId", Value = user.WebUserId }  

var argsDeleteWebUserXref2 = new DbParameter[] {         new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "WebUserId", Value = user.WebUserId }  

rowsAffectedDeleteWebUserXref += base.context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlDeleteWebUserGreen, argsDeleteWebUserXref1);      
rowsAffectedDeleteWebUserXref += base.context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlDeleteWebUserBlue, argsDeleteWebUserXref2);
```

Comment: I understand that, in straight up ADO.NET I would simply call Parameters.Clear() between calls, but I don't see such functionality exposed through Entity Framework.  Simply creating two different objects that contain the same exact parameter seems like a last resort solution to this problem don't you think?

Comment: It seems to be connecting the parameter to the stored procedure in some way, and therefore not allowing you to use it for 2 procedures at the same time.