# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have written a sample code to insert data into MySQL database using a Stored Procedure along with Entity Framework as follows:

```
MySqlParameter userName = new MySqlParameter("_UserName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
userName.Value = txtUserName.Text;
MySqlParameter password = new MySqlParameter("_Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
password.Value = txtPassword.Text;
MySqlParameter FirstName = new MySqlParameter("_FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
FirstName.Value = txtFirstName.Text;
MySqlParameter LastName = new MySqlParameter("_LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
LastName.Value = txtLastName.Text;

entities.ExecuteStoreCommand(
    "uspInsertUsers _UserName,_Password,_FirstName,_LastName",
    userName, password, FirstName, LastName);
```

I am getting an Exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uspInsertUsers 'Dorababu','sae','Dorababu','M'' at line 1

Can some one help me?

Comment: Is this as simple as `uspInsertUsers @_UserName,@_Password,@_FirstName,...` ?

Comment: still the same exception

Comment: I am using `6.3.5.0` should I change it?

Comment: Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970231/objectcontext-executestorecommand-how-to-clear-parameters-between-calls) helps

Comment: How about `uspInsertUsers ?_UserName,?_Password,?_FirstName...` or try replacing the `_` with `?`

Comment: You can also try just using ? by themselves for parameter names and placeholders; I would have expected EntityFramework to have used named parameters though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this works for me

```
MySqlParameter userName = new MySqlParameter("?UserName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
userName.Value = txtUserName.Text;
MySqlParameter password = new MySqlParameter("?Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
password.Value = txtPassword.Text;
MySqlParameter FirstName = new MySqlParameter("?FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
FirstName.Value = txtFirstName.Text;
MySqlParameter LastName = new MySqlParameter("?LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
LastName.Value = txtLastName.Text;

entities.ExecuteStoreCommand("CALL uspInsertUsers(?UserName,?Password,?FirstName,?LastName)", userName,password,FirstName,LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
entities.ExecuteStoreCommand("CALL uspInsertUsers _UserName,_Password,_FirstName,_LastName", userName,password,FirstName,LastName);
```